# Reflink cloning of LXC container on btrfs?

Tags: btrfs, lxc, cloning

I use btrfs on my system and have created an LXC container with Xubuntu on it. Now I'd like to use that as a base for other containers. Since it's a btrfs, I can use cp --reflink to create a copy-on-write copy of a file or folder. This seems kind of ideal in my use case, but I was wondering if lxc-clone will make use of that or create full copies when I use a directory backing rather than btrfs?

Answer (score 2):

You can always [bedup](https://github.com/g2p/bedup) later. It is blazingly fast (incremental run takes only seconds to finish), thanks to the advanced features of btrfs, so you can put as an upstart job.

It's not an answer, but rather a walkaround.

Comment: It is a very welcome suggestion. I didn't know about bedup. That makes things a lot easier. It means I might as well use directory backing on btrfs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, lxc-clone will utilize btrfs capability of making COW copies as it's noted in [Stephane Graber's blog entry](https://www.stgraber.org/2013/12/27/lxc-1-0-container-storage/) in the paragraph "Cloning containers" if you use switch "-s" or have set up btrfs as your backing store.

UPD. I am very sorry, but it seems that I haven't read the question to the very end. If you use directory backing storage rather than btrfs, lxc-clone will NOT make COW copies.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to update your answer. I suspected this to be the case.